# Importing AST modification

Tags: python-3.x, win32com, python-importlib, python-ast

I'm attempting dynamic rewrite of pywin32 `win32com.client` module prior to import, the below seems to work - but I'm not happy with the 6 lines of code for importing (after the last comment).  Can anyone recommend a more concise way of creating / importing the resulting module (package)?

```
import sys, ast, types
import os.path
import importlib.util

import win32com

# import ast
_win32com_client_spec = importlib.util.find_spec("win32com.client")
_win32com_client_ast = ast.parse(open(_win32com_client_spec.origin).read())

(_win32com_client_dispatch_ast,) = (x for x in _win32com_client_ast.body if isinstance(x, ast.FunctionDef) and x.name == 'Dispatch')

# rename Dispatch
_win32com_client_dispatch_ast.name = '_OldDispatch'

# create new Dispatch
_my_dispatch_mod_ast = ast.parse("""
def Dispatch(*args, **kwds):
    base_inst = _OldDispatch(*args, **kwds)
    spec_inst = _OldDispatch(base_inst)
    return spec_inst
""")
(_my_dispatch_ast,) = _my_dispatch_mod_ast.body

# insert new Dispatch in module
_win32com_client_ast.body.insert(_win32com_client_ast.body.index(_win32com_client_dispatch_ast)+1, _my_dispatch_ast)

# import the package
_my_win32com_client_co = compile(_win32com_client_ast, '<patched win32com.client>', 'exec')
_my_win32com_client_mod = types.ModuleType('win32com.client')
_my_win32com_client_mod.__path__ = (os.path.dirname(_win32com_client_spec.origin),)
sys.modules[_my_win32com_client_mod.__name__] = _my_win32com_client_mod
win32com.client = _my_win32com_client_mod
exec(_my_win32com_client_co, _my_win32com_client_mod.__dict__)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

further reading of the documentation shows using the `ModuleSpec` object is preferable to using `types.ModuleType`.

ref: https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.util.module_from_spec

the resulting code implicitly handles the `__path__` for the package, and allows to reuse the spec object throughout.  Beware if using the spec origin to show patching as below, the **file** attribute should be set explicitly as below.

The module should be imported prior to being exec'd, this seems to be important for submodule imports to work as found in `gencache` modules e.g. `import win32com.client.CLSISToClass`:

```
import sys, ast
import importlib.util

import win32com

if 'win32com.client' not in sys.modules:
    # import ast
    _win32com_client_spec = importlib.util.find_spec("win32com.client")
    _win32com_client_path = _win32com_client_spec.origin
    _win32com_client_spec.origin = '<patched win32com.client>'
    _win32com_client_ast = ast.parse(open(_win32com_client_path).read())

    # rename Dispatch
    (_win32com_client_dispatch_ast,) = (x for x in _win32com_client_ast.body if isinstance(x, ast.FunctionDef) and x.name == 'Dispatch')
    _win32com_client_dispatch_ast.name = '_OldDispatch'

    # create new Dispatch (disregard line numbers)
    _my_dispatch_mod_ast = ast.parse("""
def Dispatch(*args, **kwds):
    base_inst = _OldDispatch(*args, **kwds)
    spec_inst = _OldDispatch(base_inst)
    return spec_inst
""")
    (_my_dispatch_ast,) = _my_dispatch_mod_ast.body

    # insert new Dispatch in module
    _win32com_client_ast.body.insert(_win32com_client_ast.body.index(_win32com_client_dispatch_ast)+1, _my_dispatch_ast)

    # compile (original path for debugging), create, import and exec the module
    _my_win32com_client_co = compile(_win32com_client_ast, _win32com_client_path, 'exec')
    _my_win32com_client_mod = importlib.util.module_from_spec(_win32com_client_spec)
    _my_win32com_client_mod.__file__ = _win32com_client_path
    win32com.client = sys.modules['win32com.client'] = _my_win32com_client_mod
    try:
        exec(_my_win32com_client_co, _my_win32com_client_mod.__dict__)
    except:
        del win32com.client, sys.modules['win32com.client']
        raise
```